# VLOOKUP with two criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a formula that returns a value from the first line matching two or more criteria? For example, "return column C from the first line where column A = x AND column B = y". I'd like to do it without concatenating column A and column B.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horizontal look up with multiple criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479299/horizontal-look-up-with-multiple-criteria)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

True = 1, False = 0

D1 returns 0 because 0 * 1 * 8 = 0

D2 returns 9 because 1 * 1 * 9= 9

[image]

This should let you change the criteria:
[image]

Comment: The problem is that I can only use a single criterion. I can't search for criteria x & y on line 1, criterion x & z on line 2 and so on... I have a high number of criteria (about one per 10 lines in a 100k lines sheet). Is there be a solution for this?

Answer (score 5):

I use INDEX/MATCH for this. Ex:

I have a table of data and want to return the value in column C where the value in column A is "c" and the value in column B is "h".

[image: sample layout]

I would use the following array formula:

`=INDEX($C$1:$C$5,MATCH(1,(($A$1:$A$5="c")*($B$1:$B$5="h")),0))`

Commit the formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

After entering the formula, you can use Excel's formula auditing tools to step through the evaluation to see how it calculates.

Answer (score 3):

`SUMPRODUCT` definitely has value when the sum over multiple criteria matches is needed. But the way I read your question, you want something like `VLOOKUP` that returns the first match. Try this:

[image: Multiple Criteria INDEX MATCH]

For your convenience the formula in `G2` is as follows -- requires array entry (`Ctrl+Shift+Enter`)

[edit: I updated the formula here but not in the screen shot]
`=INDEX($C$1:$C$6,MATCH(E2&"|"&F2,$A$1:$A$6&"|"&$B$1:$B$6,0))`

Two things to note:

1. `SUMPRODUCT` won't work if the result type is not numeric
2. `SUMPRODUCT` will return the `SUM` of results matching the criteria, not the first match (as `VLOOKUP` does)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can use the [SUMPRODUCT function](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/04/21/vlookup-on-two-columns/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think what he is asking is typical multiple results display option in excel. It can be done [using Small, and row function in arrays](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/how-to-look-up-a-value-in-a-list-and-return-multiple-corresponding-values-HA001226038.aspx).

This display all the results that matches the different criteria

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that shows how to do this using SUMPRODUCT and table header lookups. The main advantage to this: it works with any value, numeric or otherwise.

So let's say we have headers H1, H2 and H3 on some table called MyTable. And let's say we are entering this into row 1, possibly on another sheet. And we want to match H1, H2 to x, y on that sheet, respectively, while returning the matching value in H3. Then the formula would be as follows:

```
=INDEX(MyTable[H3], ROUND(SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(TRUE, (MyTable[H1] & MyTable[H2]) = ($x1 & $y1),0)),0),1)
```

What does it do? The sum-product ensures everything is treated as arrays. So you can contatenate entire table columns together to make an array of concatenated valued, dynamically calculated. And then you can compare these to the existing values in x and y- somehow magically you can compare the concatenated array from the table to the individual concatenation of x & y. Which gives you an array of true false values. Matching that to true yields the first match of the lookup. And then all we need to do is go back and index that in the original table.

### Notes

The rounding is just in there to make sure the Index function gets back an integer. I got #N/A values until I rounded.

It might be more instructive to run this through the evaluator to see what's going on...

This can easily be modified to work with a non table - just replace the table references with raw ranges. The tables are clearer though, so use them if possible. I found the original source for this here: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/04/21/vlookup-on-two-columns/. But there was a bug with rouding values to INTs so I fixed that.