# Return a row number that matches multiple criteria in vbs excel

Tags: excel, search, vba, criteria

I need to be able to search my whole table for a row that matches multiple criteria. We use a program that outputs data in the form of a .csv file. It has rows that separate sets of data, each of these headers don't have any columns that are unique in of them self but if i searched the table for multiple values i should be able to pinpoint each header row. I know i can use Application.WorksheetFunction.Match to return a row on a single criteria but i need to search on two three or four criteria.

In pseudo-code it would be something like this:

```
Return row number were column A = bill & column B = Woods & column C = some other data
```

Comment: sorry i just updated my post, it needs to be in vba for excel so i can write a macro.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do this in VBA versus applying filters or using worksheet formulas?

Comment: If a formula would help, you can use something like this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583461/vlookup-with-two-criteria/10583676#10583676

Answer (score 1):

We need to work with arrays:

There are 2 kinds of arrays:

```
    numeric {1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1}
    boolean {TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE}
```

to convert between them we can use:

```
    MATCH function
    MATCH(1,{1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1},0)  -> will result {TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE}

    simple multiplication
    {TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE}*{TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE} -> will result {1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1}
```

you can can check an array in the match function, entering it like in the picture below, be warned that MATCH function WILL TREAT AN ARRAY AS AN "OR" FUNCTION (one match will result in true
ie:

```
    MATCH(1,{1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1},0)=TRUE
    , YOU MUST CTR+SHIFT+ENTER !!! FOR IT TO GIVE AN ARRAY BACK!!!
```

in the example below i show that i want to sum the hours of all the employees except the admin per case

we have 2 options, the long simple way, the complicated fast way:

```
    long simple way
    D2=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C9,(A2=A2:A9)*("admin"<>B2:B9)) <<- SUMPRODUCT makes a multiplication
```

basically A1={2,3,11,3,2,4,5,6}*{0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0} (IT MUST BE A NUMERIC ARRAY TO THE RIGHT IN SUMPRODUCT!!!)
ie: A1=2*0+3*1+11*1+3*0+2*0+4*0+5*0+6*0

this causes a problem because if you drag the cell to autocomplete the rest of the cells, it will edit the lower and higher values of 
ie:  D9=SUMPRODUCT(C9:C16,(A9=A9:A16)*("admin"<>B9:B16)), which is out of bounds
same as the above if you have a table and want to view the results in a diferent order

```
    the fast complicated way
    D3=SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT("c2:c9"),(A3=INDIRECT("a2:a9"))*("admin"<>INDIRECT("b2:b9")))
```

it's the same, except that INDIRECT was used on the cells that we want not be modified when autocompleting or table reorderings
be warned that INDIRECT sometimes give VOLATILE ERROR,i recommend not using it on a single cell or using it only once in an array

f* c* i cant post pictures :(
table is:

```
    case    emplyee hours   totalHoursPerCaseWithoutAdmin
    1   admin   2   14
    1   him 3   14
    1   her 11  14
    2   him 3   5
    2   her 2   5
    3   you 4   10
    3   admin   5   10
    3   her 6   10
```

and for the functions to check the arrays, open the insert function button (it looks like and fx) then doubleclick MATCH and then if you enter inside the Lookup_array a value like
A2=A2:A9 for our example it will give {TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE} that is because only the first 3 lines are from case=1

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

Assuming that you data in in A1:C20

I am looking for "Bill" in `A`, "Woods" in `B` and "some other data" in `C`

Change as applicable

=IF(INDEX(A1:A20,MATCH("Bill",A1:A20,0),1)="Bill",IF(INDEX(B1:B20,MATCH("Woods",B1:B20,0),1)="Woods",IF(INDEX(C1:C20,MATCH("some other data",C1:C20,0),1)="some other data",MATCH("Bill",A1:A20,0),"Not Found")))

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use this array* formula (for three criteria):

```
=MATCH(1,((Range1=Criterion1)*(Range2=Criterion2)*(Range3=Criterion3)),0)
```

*commit with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`