# Horizontal look up with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, libreoffice, vlookup

I am trying to develop the formula in excel to look up multiple criteria. Specifically, how do I pull in a value for apples in NYC for location (B)?

```
    Northeast                                        NYC            
     (A)     (B)         (C)     (D)         (A)     (B)    (C)      (D)


Grapes   3,000   2,073   751     2,000       4,253   3,500   1,832   2,500 
Apples   400     3,076   2,298   900         27,250  19,000  14,250  9,000 
Oranges  6.0     3.1     3.9     5.0         28.4    20.0    13.8    10.0
```

Answer (score 3):

I have gotten the following formula to work with your data with one minor issue, you will need to fill the header columns (Northeast/NYC) to allow the match to work

```
=VLOOKUP(A9,A1:I5,MATCH((B9&C9),(A1:I1&A2:I2),0),FALSE)
```

**NB: Because the formula is using an array function you will need to execute it using the Crl-Shift-Enter command :)

here is a screenshot to let you decipher the references :)

[image: Sheet]

I hope this is helpful