# Excel - How to find output from two separate look ups and between values

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I am trying to find the output (banding in the below example) based on the combination of the values in the first column (A1 and B2) and another number that falls between the min and max banding.

It's hard for me to explain but trying an example, say the first column (A1 and B2) are car brands. For a car brand that is A1 and priced at 2, I would expect the output to be AAA banding. For a car brand that is B2 and priced at 9 I would expect the output to be CCC banding.

How can I populate the output using Excel formulas, I have looked into an Index-Match function but I am currently stumped given it is difficult since the banding might be the same, but the values that fall between them differ between car brands.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use following array formula. Array formula means you have to press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` after typing formula in cell.

```
=INDEX(D2:D9,MIN(IF(A2:A9=F2,IF(B2:B9<=G2,IF(C2:C9>=G2,ROW(D2:D9)-ROW(D1))))))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]

> If you prefer non array formula then you can use this formula.

```
=INDEX(D2:D9,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(D2:D9)-ROW(D1))/((A2:A9=F2)*(B2:B9<=G2)*(C2:C9>=G2)),1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to do what's known as a double VLOOKUP: [VLOOKUP with two criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583461/vlookup-with-two-criteria)

There are a couple of options there, and be wary that the INDEX(MATCH()) method uses array formulas.

Here is an example of what a formula would look like:

```
=INDEX(D2:D9,SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(1,(A2:A9=[car])*(B2:B9<=[price])*(C2:C9>[price]),0)))
```

Just replace `[car]` and `[price]` with cell references (or hard-coded values).

Answer (score 1):

Index/Match is possible without array formulas. Compare the formula with the screenshot.

```
=INDEX(INDEX(D:D,MATCH($H$2,A:A,0)):INDEX(D:D,MATCH($H$2,A:A,1)),MATCH($H$3,INDEX(B:B,MATCH($H$2,A:A,0)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH($H$2,A:A,1)),1))
```

[image]