# Excel Lookup, if criteria a and criteria b match then return value on x

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I'm trying to get the value on column "I" if value in A= L2 AND value in C = M2. How would I go about that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VLOOKUP with two criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583461/vlookup-with-two-criteria)

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
=INDEX($I$2:$I$20,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$20=L2)*($C$2:$C$20=M2),0))
```

With ***Microsoft 365*** you can use `XLOOKUP()`

```
=XLOOKUP(1,($A$2:$A$20=L2)*($C$2:$C$20=M2),$I$2:$I$20,"")
```